# Tableview cell setup using a ternery operator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I wonder if anyone can offer any guidance?  I am writing an iPhone app, using Xcode 13.2.1.  I am displaying a tableview within a scene that uses XIBs.  It works fine.  Above the table I have a header that is being displayed, it too works fine.

However, what I'd like to do is display the header, then display a cell that doesn't use the XIB (and that is a height of 50), and then displays every other cell after that first cell using a XIB (height is 195 - just an FYI).  Thus, to do/implement this what I am trying to do is implement some kind of 'if statement' such that if indexPath.row is 0 then set the cell type to <call it cell type 1>, and if the indexPath.row is not 0 then set the cell type to <call it cell type 2>.  I don't believe that I can use an IF statement because later in the code block it won't recognise the value of cell because it would have been set in an IF statement.  Hence, I think I need to use a turnery operator, however I am struggling to construct the turnery operator.

The current code that sets up the cell for XIB in the

```
// MARK: TableView CELL Information
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    // Current code that sets up the cell for a XIB template
    guard let cell: CustomTableViewCellTypeA = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as? CustomTableViewCellTypeA else {
        os_log("Dequeued cell isn't an instance of CustomTableViewCellTypeA", log: .default, type: .debug)
        fatalError()
    }
```

I KNOW THE FOLLOWING CODE DOESN'T WORK - however I am showing it this way to try and explain what I am trying to achieve:

```
// Intent is to use an IF or turnery operator to set the correct cell type
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    } else {
        // Current code that sets up the cell for a XIB template
        guard let cell: CustomTableViewCellTypeA = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as? CustomTableViewCellTypeA else {
            os_log("Dequeued cell isn't an instance of CustomTableViewCellTypeA", log: .default, type: .debug)
            fatalError()
        }
    }
```

The follow on code (if I can somehow get the above to work) would mean that I would display some information in the first cell which would be <call it cell type 1> and then display other information in <call it cell type 2>.

Anyone done this before or would have any guidance on how to create such a turnery operator?  I have tried many things but can't seem to manage to find the solution.

Cheers James.

Comment: What you are doing will work. You can dequeue a different cell class based on your index path. You also need to implement `UITableViewDelegate - heightForRowAt indexPath` to give a different height based on the `indexPath` - what is not working for you ?

Comment: Yep. There's no reason you can't use an `if` statement. Also, there is no point in messing around with the guard and fatal error.  Just force downcast. It's going to crash anyway

Answer (score 1):

Actually this was much easier to solve than trying to add complexity of turnery operators to determine which cell to dequeue.  It was simply a case of using an IF and adding in the code I wanted to execute along with ensuring I put a return cell statement in it, meaning that if the IF-statement wasn't executed then the code executes the other dequeue statement...  Thus, the code looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    

    if indexPath.row < 1 {
                
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Select/tap on an event record below to edit the details of the journey."
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.backgroundColor = .orange
        return cell
        
    }
    
    guard let cell: CustomTableViewCellTypeA = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as? CustomTableViewCellTypeA else {
        os_log("Dequeued cell isn't an instance of CustomTableViewCellTypeA", log: .default, type: .debug)
            fatalError()
    }
```

This gave me the result I needed.  Also, the feedback from  Shawn Frank above helped me realise I hadn't registered the first cell type (only the second one), thus when I registered both the first and second cell types within the class it all worked beautifully.  Thank you to all who looked at the question and the fine folks above who gave guidance.  Cheers James.